# After selecting the dropdown option gets bolded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a dropdown and somehow I am getting this issue with it.

[image: Dropdown]

This is how my dropdown is. Please have a look the font size. Now when I select one of the options from the dropdown, for some reason It is getting bold.
[image], like this.

I am not able to generate its fiddle as it is completely customized.

Just wanted to check If anyone else have faced this.

Thanks

```
     <div class="dropdown tobeaddedtodropdown3  tobeaddedtodropdown3-dd" style="position: relative;display: inline;">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle tobeaddedtobutton3- dd signuptitle" style="" type="button" id="dropdownMenu122" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" value="Mrs.">Mrs.</button>
  <span class="caret downarrow downarrowsmall downarrowsmall-dd dd-1  open"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dd tobeaddedtoul3  tobeaddedtoul3-dd" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
     <li role="presentation" class="testli3 testli3-dd">
     <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Mr.');$('#user_title').val('Mr.');"> Mr.</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class="testli3 testli3-dd">
     <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Ms.');$('#user_title').val('Ms.');">                      Ms .</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="testli3 testli3-dd">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="$('#dropdownMenu122').text('Mrs.');$('#user_title').val('Mrs.');"      >Mrs.</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Update: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qs8enwk1/2/), not exactly working

Comment: I faced it. This is quite easy to fix, just adjust styles.

Comment: Can you please post the css for it.

Comment: It's not default browser dropdown. So make fiddle (yes, you can, because you have code for that) or you will get no help.

Comment: trouble in creating the fiddle is It is been done by someone else, 5-7 images being used as borders,separators,arrows. So I am not able to get it as similar to what I have with my complete code. Let me give it a try though

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/qs8enwk1/2/` This is somewhat I am able to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('option').change(function () {
       $(this).find('option:selected').css('font-size', 'size_you_want');
    }).trigger('change');
```